# std errors in poisson glm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution

With this data:

```
ds <- data.frame(y=1:10,z=rep(c("A","B"),each=5))
```

I fit this model:

```
summary(glm(y ~ z, family = poisson, data = ds))

> Call:
glm(formula = y ~ z, family = poisson, data = ds)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3427  -0.5515   0.0000   0.4984   1.0527  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.0986     0.2582   4.255 2.09e-05 ***
zB            0.9808     0.3028   3.240   0.0012 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 16.643  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  4.852  on 8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 42.818

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

As I understand it the estimate for `A` is `exp(1.0986 - 0.9808)` and `B` is `exp(1.0986 + 0.9808)` .

If I were doing a barplot of this model I would put the std errors for `B` as:

```
 `exp(1.0986 + 0.9808) + or - exp(0.3028)` .
```

Would `A` be:

```
`exp(1.0986 - 0.9808) + or - exp(0.3028)`  ?
```

---

If I was plotting the results as i suggested above the values would  be:

```
results <- read.table(text = " y           z     error
                              1.125019     a     1.353644
                              7.999668     b     1.353644", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

limits <- aes(ymax = y + error, ymin = y - error)
ggplot(results, aes(x=z,y=y)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill= z)) +
    geom_errorbar(limits)
```

What should be the correct values in this plot?

Comment: Sequence 1:10 is NOT from poisson distribution...

Comment: yes, please dont worry about the actual data, clearly this is a contrived example...

Comment: I don't think your understanding regarding the estimates is correct. Have you changed the contrast settings or are you using R's default? Also, I wouldn't expect error bars from a model with a log link to be symmetrical on the original scale.

Comment: thank for your response @Roland, I guess I must be confused. I hope at least that using `exp` is correct as poisson is modeling log counts, No I havent changed contrast settings in R. I didnt think they should be symmetrical either which led me to my confusion over interpretation.

Comment: Am I missing something, glm return error, Error in family() : argument "lambda" is missing, with no default and can t repeat this output you have ...  glm(formula = y ~ z, family = poisson, data = ds)
Error in family() : argument "lambda" is missing, with no default" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, simulate:

```
#some data
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e4
y1 <- rpois(n, 10)
y2 <- rpois(n, 100)

DF <- data.frame(y=c(y1, y2), 
                 z=rep(c("A", "B"), each=n))

#note that I exclude the intercept
mod <- glm(y ~ z-1, family = poisson, data = DF)

coeffs <- exp(coef(mod))
#     A        B 
#9.9845 100.0964

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=z, y=y)) + 
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(data=data.frame(y=coeffs, z=c("A", "B")), color="red", size=5)
```

[image]

See [How to obtain those nasty standard errors from transformed data - and why they should not be used](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029095149/http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.47.9023&rep=rep1&type=pdf) regarding obtaining standard errors on the original scale. They also warn that confidence intervals calculated from these with the assumption of symmetry might strongly deviate from the real confidence intervals if the transformation is strongly non-linear.

In our example:

```
ses <- coeffs*summary(mod)$coef[,2]
#        zA         zB 
#0.03159825 0.10004819

#variance should be equal to mean
(ses*sqrt(1e4))^2
#      zA         zB 
#9.984492 100.096400
```

If you don't (or can't) exclude the intercept, things get messy and you'd need some kind of error propagation. But then, it would be better to obtain confidence intervals by other means anyway.

Comment: Thank you Roland I will have  a look at the linked info. Can I ask your opinion then how you would report these results? Assuming you cant remove intercept as you may have other continuous covariates Imagining you had similar data, and you wanted to show the estimates for `A` and `B` in `z`?

Comment: I would probably report the model coefficients and their standard errors on the transformed scale and explain to the non-statistically minded reader that treatment "A" is described by the intercept and the other coefficients are the treatment differences to this. If you need something else (e.g., on the original scale), you need to explain more clearly what you need. I might try to show a graph with predictions and add a confidence band to this graph.

Comment: Hi Roland thanks again, I had in mind something like the ggplot example i showed biuth with CIs

Comment: @user1322296 I think you are looking for confidence intervals for predictions. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14424417/1412059

Comment: Link to "How to obtain..." is dead. It looks interesting, any chance of reviving it?

Comment: @dariober Done.